# How to retrieve email address of current user?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

In Google Spreadsheet I am having the following issue:

I am using `Session.getActiveUser().getUserLoginId()` to fetch the current user's email id but other than creator of the spreadsheet it is returning empty string. I have also used `getEffectiveUser()` but no help.

I have even deployed this to "User accessing the web app" but still it's not working.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6):

## Short answer

`getUserLoginID` is deprecated. Instead use `getMail`.

## Explanation

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user

### getuserLoginID()

> Deprecated. As of June 24, 2013, replaced by getEmail()

### getEmail()

> Gets the user's email address, if available. If security policies do
>   not allow access to the user's email address, this method returns a
>   blank string. The circumstances in which the email address is
>   available vary: for example, the user's email address is not available
>   in any context that allows a script to run without that user's
>   authorization, like a simple onOpen(e) or onEdit(e) trigger, a custom
>   function in Google Sheets, or a web app deployed to "execute as me"
>   (that is, authorized by the developer instead of the user). However,
>   these restrictions generally do not apply if the developer and the
>   user belong to the same Google Apps for Business domain.
>
> ```
>  // Log the email address of the person running the script.
>  Logger.log(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail());
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.   
Can you please let me know how can i make it authorized by asking the user?

Comment: @chetanp: See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization. If you need something more specific, post a new question including more details.

Comment: However if there's multiple user sessions in the same browser, it will only get /u/0 even if you are using /u/1 to access the document.

Answer (score 4):

[Wim den Herder posted a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40329590/) based on the observation that a script cannot remove the current user from the list of editors of a protected range. They key part is as follows:

```
var protection = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange("A1").protect();
protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
var editors = protection.getEditors();
protection.remove();
```

The first line protects cell A1.
The second line attempts to remove all editors of a protected range. Any editors that are left are the spreadsheet owner and the current user. The protection is then removed altogether.

Answer (score 1):

It's a late answer, but I posted it because I had the same problem, and the folowing unswer solved it for me :

To get the email address of the curent user you can use this function and it will return the email address saved in a variable :

```
function OnOpen(){
   var emailName = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
   var optionsHtml = emailName.toString().split(",");

   return optionsHtml;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What happens if google sheet is opened by several users in same time ?
Actually, I want to protect some cells for a specific user, dynamically according to his name/his email. I need to retrieve his email to do that, but no idea if several users in same time...

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. On this site, answer post should answer the question. If you a question related to an answer, please post it as new question self-contained including a link to the related answer.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/146674)